# adb devices doesn't show phone linux Fedora

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt, fedora

First of all, I have a LG G2, and I'm using `Fedora`.
When I issue an `adb devices` command, I see no devices.

**Steps I have taken to correct this:**

- I have added the following to my `51-android.rules` file. The first line is for another device.

> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4366", MODE="0666"
>   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", ATTRS{idProduct}=="621c",MODE="0666"

- I have added 0x1004 to my `adb_usb.ini` file.
- I have restarted adb (by issuing "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server")
- I have enabled debugging on my phone (by turning on **Developer Options** and checking **USB Debugging** under settings)
- `lsusb` command returns the following

> Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1004:621c LG Electronics, Inc.

Comment: Do you get the device if you use `sudo adb start-server` and `sudo adb devices`? Have you issued command `udevadm control --reload-rules`??

Comment: @Alex Cohn: I just issued `adb kill-server` then `sudo adb start-server` then `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`, then `adb devices`. Still a no-go.

Comment: Actually, running adb from sudo is *instead of* working with `udev` rules. Sorry this didn't work.

Comment: One more question: does your device show the USB debug notification? Does it show the regular USB notification (mount to copy files, etc)?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, when I hook the usb to the phone, the phone first says `USB Connected: Connected as installer`. Then a few seconds later, it says `USB Connected: Media Sync(MTP)`

Comment: Right, you understood my question correctly. My Nexus S device, for example, does not think it has a USB connection to my PC - sometimes. It's a hardware problem. Naturally, no way **adb** will recognize the device in such situation :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what I did to resolve this is:

1. I had my USB cable plugged into the wrong port. I have 6 different ports, so I guess that first one I tried was messed up.
2. I had to change my USB Connection Method to "Internet Connection->Ethernet"
3. I had to enable installation from unknown sources. I went to Settings->Security->Checked "Unknown Source"
4. I had to Check "USB Debugging" BEFORE I hooked the USB cable up to my phone
5. I had to use the original cable shipped with my phone